# Удаление дубликатов с вынесением конфликтующих значений в отдельный столбец, PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется таблица

```
 name | value 
------+-------
 a    | x
 a    | y
 b    | x
 b    | y
 b    | z
 c    | x
 d    | y
 d    | z
(8 rows)
```

В ней различным именам могут соответствовать различные значения. Известно, что каждому имени соответствует не более трех значений. Необходимо одним запросом получить следующую таблицу.

```
 name | value1 | value2 | value3 
------+--------+--------+--------
 a    | x      | y      | 
 b    | x      | y      | z
 c    | x      |        | 
 d    | y      | z      |
```

Как этого достичь?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT name, 
       value, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY value) rn
FROM test
)
SELECT name, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN value END) value1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN value END) value2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=3 THEN value END) value3
FROM cte
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5bcf488fa1a93536cb0a5ce280d46ac5)